# Can't manage redirect with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

I have a new error with the code below. What I'm trying to do is to build a simple login system, but I have a problem with redirecting `res.redirect('/example')`.
When I try to redirect users the console.log says that Headers have been already sent. I know that there are other questions similar to this but I'm not able to solve this problem. Please help

**The file below is the main controller:**

```js
exports.login = function(req, res){
  var email = req.body.email,
      password = req.body.password;

      User.findOne({email: email, password: password}, function(err,obj) {
      if(obj){

        console.log(obj);
          console.log('Access approved');
            req.session.regenerate(function(){
            console.log('New session printed to Sessions DB'); 
            req.session.email = email;
            res.redirect('/sec');
          });
      } else if(!email || !password){
        console.log('Please insert data');
      }else if(err){
        console.log('Error');
        req.session.regenerate( function(){
          req.session.msg = err;
          res.redirect('/login');
        });
      } else {
        console.log('errore not authenticated user');
          req.session.msg = err;
          res.redirect('/login');
      }

     });

   };
```

**This is the Routes file:**

```
app.post('/logUser', users.login)
```

**And the node:**

```
app.use('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('public/login.html', {root: __dirname });
});
```

Comment: Could you post exactly what is being logged to the console?

Comment: Yes but on my console all I can see is only this 'Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.'

Comment: That error usually happens when you're trying to do something with the `res` object after you send it. By calling `sendFile` or `redirect`, you're sending it. Make sure your code only does one of these things, not both. You can put logs before each operation you do with `res` to check and see if both are getting hit

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found the solution and it's pretty simple. 
I need to add `next();` to node file, like this:

```
app.use('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('public/login.html', {root: __dirname });
    next();
});
```

Probably it happen because setting `next` I can change headers that have been already sent and finally I can reset it again with `res.redirect`

Comment: Thank you anyway guys for your support!